# Pandas .transform(list) to convert every element in column into singleton list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert every element `x` in a pandas df column to `[x]`. Right now, I'm using `df['col'].transform(lambda x: [x])` but it's slow, and I was hoping to speed it up by using `df['col'.transform('list')` where the `list` refers to the constructor method, that I hoped, would be faster since it's built into python. This doesn't compile, giving a `Transform function failed`, and if I use `.transform(list)` without the single quotes, I get a `Function did not transform` error instead. I also get errors when trying to use `apply()`.

Comment: Try `df["col"].values.reshape(-1, 1)`?

Comment: This returns a `np.ndarray` but I want to modify the dataframe instead, and so to return a dataframe, where every entry `x` has been replaced by `[x]`. So this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `numpy.reshape` and `tolist`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": np.arange(1000)})
df["col"] = df["col"].values.reshape(-1, 1).tolist()
```

Output:

```
print(df.head())
   col
0  [0]
1  [1]
2  [2]
3  [3]
4  [4]
```

Benchmark (~4x faster):

```
%timeit df["col"].values.reshape(-1, 1).tolist()
# 50.9 µs ± 770 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit df["col"].transform(lambda x: [x])
# 188 µs ± 2.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: One thing to note is that `transform` returns a series and `tolist()` returns a list. I need the data returned as a series, so would have to wrap the `.values` solution you've given in `pd.Series` -- I wonder if that will make it slower? EDIT: %timeit gives: `9.75 ms ± 262 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
8.14 ms ± 130 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`, and so it seems your solution is not really faster.

Comment: It will. Note that it is almost never a good idea to have an array (or series) of objects (e.g. list), which will make most of the operations very slow. Unless you have to use `pandas` api, I would strongly recommend using it via `numpy` as 2-d array. That being said, what is it that you **actually** want to do?

Comment: My actual goal is this: I have columns `c1, c2...c30` that contain floats. I want to create a new column `c1_c2` (many of these in fact) that takes the float in `c1`, call it `val1`, and the float in `c2`, call it `val2`, and writes `[val1, val2]` to this new column `c1_c2`, and does this in a fast vectorized manner.

Comment: @TanishqKumar that is very different from what you asked originally and it seems you are just scratching the surface of your requirement :)

Comment: The reason I asked my question is because I have implemented the logic for everything, and everything runs fast and outputs correct except for the one step `.transform(lambda x: [x])`, so that was the only part that's relevant. I appreciate your attempts to help a lot, but I still haven't found a faster alternative to that!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are probably looking for every element (not just one column) to be made as list:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: [x])
```

Comment: Is this going to be faster than `.transform`? Why? EDIT: In fact, I just ran `cProfile` on `map` and `transform` and it seems `transform is marginally faster if not about the same speed, so this seems to be no improvement. Is there no way to use the `list` constructor and avoid the lambda function, which is taking the bulk of the time?